# Read a file(.csv) file and extract file name from it using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Read a file and extract the file name from it. Need to remove digit and extra charactres from the file and print output.

For ie:if the file name is 53943_Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx" or Sreerag_cde_one_check.xlsx and output should be "Sreerag

Code i have tried.

```
ini_string = pd.read_csv("D:\wGroup_000005 KutakW Special_RSLRpt_PD2021-06-16_Run_as_2021_6 _on_20210616_PKG_5.csv")
final = ini_string.split("_")
try:
    # Check if the first value is int.
    int(final[0])
    Name=final[1].upper()
    print(Name)
except:
    Name=final[0].upper()
    print(Name)
```

Comment: What is the format of data? How many columns are there? Please post sample data.

Comment: The part about _reading_ the file seems to be completely irrelevant here. Please review the guidance for focusing your question to just a [mre]

Comment: help me to just extract file name from file itself using pandas .are you confused with column or row.a file always has file name right ,i need to extract that only

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to read the file into a dataframe first to get something from the filename. Perform all your operations on filename directly

Comment: Can you help me with a sample code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).